# How to create a/multiple stored procedure in Teradata by running script file

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

For the below stored procedure in Teradara DB, I am able to crate it when running it as a sql statement. But when I am trying to run it through SQl script file, it's not getting created and throws error messgae:

`SQL Error [5526] [HY000]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.33] [Error 5526] [SQLState HY000] Stored Procedure is not created/replaced due to error(s).`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.SELECT_PROCEDURE(IN ROLL_ INTEGER,OUT MARKS_ 
FLOAT)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
    SELECT MARKS INTO MARKS_ FROM SCHEMA.TEST WHERE ROLL = :ROLL_;
END;
```

I have also searched the error on internet, but didn't get much help.
Help here, please !

Comment: what is the command that you are running to compile the proc using the file

Comment: How is this script file called? Seems like it was split in multiple parts, i.e. up to the first `;` and then the remainder...

Comment: I am running the file in DBeaver by clicking on [Execute Script] button. Same is running fine when I clicked on [Execute SQL Statement] button.
@AritraBhattacharya

Comment: Script is called through DBeaver.
@dnoeth

Comment: Frim the DBeaver manual: *This executes all queries in the current editor (or selected queries) as a script. DBeaver parses queries one by one using a statement delimiter (“;” by default) and executes them consecutively. You can configure the script execution behavior in the SQL editor preferences (Right-click the script and click Preferences on the context menu).*

Comment: Not able to create procedure even by doing the changes as you have stated. :(
@dnoeth